# I want get distance matrix by mahout mapreduce job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, mahout

I have these input file

```
id, feature1, feature2, ...
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, ...
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, ...
2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, ...
```

and I want get its distance matrix calculate by hadoop or mahout using mapreduce job.
but mahout has no method of calculate distance matrix.
What do I do?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the distance between each records yourself using Mahout.
Use distance method of [DistanceMeasure class](https://builds.apache.org/job/Mahout-Quality/javadoc/org/apache/mahout/common/distance/DistanceMeasure.html),  but you have to convert the input file into SequenceFile first.

Comment: by mapreduce, DistanceMeasure class can use? (input file had been converted to SequenceFile already)